# How to add looping within an angular interpolation expression

Tags: angular

Working with the latest version of angular, and I need to modify an interpolation expression as detailed below. I've changed names and code for this post, hope what I've provided is clear and sufficient.

Part of my product-list.component,html is this table. Note the line with the customer name join:

```
<table mat-table #ProductList [dataSource]="ProductListData" class="table-sm">
.....
  <ng-container matColumnDef="ProductName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Product Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.productName}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="CustomerNames">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Customer Name(s) </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.customerNames.join(', ')}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
.....
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="ProductListColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ProductListColumns;"></mat-row>
</table>
```

In the product-list.component.ts file, I have the following datasource defined:

```
    ProductListData: IProductList[] = [];
```

I load ProductListData by pushing IProductList items:

```
this.ProductListData.push(p as IProductList)
```

where p is built just before that line.

In another ts file that I import into product-list.component.ts, is the interface:

```
export interface IProductList {
.....
  productName: string;
  customerNames: string[];
.....
};
```

This all works as expected. If customerNames is an array of three names, the names are shown in one string, with names comma separated. However I needed to modify my interface by replacing customerNames in IProductList with an array of ICustomer:

```
export interface IProductList {
.....
  productName: string;
  customers: ICustomer[];
.....
};
```

where ICustomer is:

```
export interface ICustomer {
.....
  customerId: int;
  customerName: string;
  customerType: string;
.....
};
```

But now that original join line in the template file needs to be reworked:

`<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.customerNames.join(', ')}} </mat-cell>`

Is it possible to change that line to interpolate like this:

`<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{loop through all customerName in customers and output as a string}} </mat-cell>`

If so, how? I am having no luck in figuring it out. If it's not possible, what's the best way to accomplish getting that string of customer names, ideally with the least amount of code change? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you could simply do an *ngFor there to loop through the customer objects en interpolate just the customerName there?

Answer (score 0):

```
{{loop through all customerName in customers and output as a string}}
```

to

```
{{ getCustomerNameInCustomers() }}
```

in ts

```
getCustomerNameInCustomers(){
  return customers.map(customer=> customer.name).join(',');
}
```

don't know if the variable names are correct, you can change them according to your code

Comment: Probably not a great idea to do method calls from the template..

Comment: @Talha: I need to access my ICustomer array that is in the IProductList array. I will test but will this approach work on every IProductList array element? In other words, when the first product is being loaded as the first row in the table, the customers for that product then need to be iterated for the join. So that row needs to be passed into the function too?

Comment: @BarnumBailey yes you should pass that object in that case, and as MikeOne mentioned, if you don't want to call a function in HTML, you can always use pipe.

Comment: As an addition to this just to clarify to reasonings for the answers: Angular HTML renders everything based on the changes and it has a built in system to check if somethin needs to be re-rendered or not. However if you start placing your own logic such as methods inside HTML, angular does not know when these should be rendered so that same method can be called 100 + in matter of seconds. Pipes allow you to write your custom methods that will run ONLY when the variable given to it changes. @BarnumBailey